# how to use custom image inside another custom image in docker

Tags: docker, sbt

I have an sbt project lets say DemoProject it depend on another sbt project commonsProject The DemoProject used a jar of commonsProject in it for that i created two custom images first for commonsProject and second for DemoProject 
here is the DockerFile for commonsProject

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8

MAINTAINER name <name@gmail.com>

ADD . /project-commons

WORKDIR /project-commons

# Define default command.
CMD ["sbt", "publishLocal"]
```

and i build the image with `docker build project-commons:v1 .`

and here is the Dockerfile for DemoProject

```
FROM project-commons:v1 

MAINTAINER name <name@gmail.com>

WORKDIR /project-commons

ADD  . /home/user/.ivy2/local/project-commons_2.12/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/project-commons_2.12.jar
# Define default command.
CMD ["sbt","publishLocal"]

FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8

MAINTAINER name <name@gmail.com>

WORKDIR /project-demo

ADD . /project-demo

# Define default command.
CMD ["sbt", "run"]
```

and built it `docker build project-demo:v1` and run it

```
docker run project-demo
```

but in the logs i got the exception of unresolved dependency of project-commons.jar it says jar not found
what i am i missing here ? i am beginner in docker please guide me

Comment: Can you share the project commons dir?

Comment: ~/git/project-commons

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). In the seconds stage (which starts in the second `FROM`) you have to specify what files to add from the previous stage:

```
FROM project-commons:v1 as firstStage

MAINTAINER name <name@gmail.com>

WORKDIR /project-commons

ADD  . /home/user/.ivy2/local/project-commons_2.12/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/project-commons_2.12.jar
# Define default command.
CMD ["sbt","publishLocal"]

FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.2_2.12.8_1.2.8

MAINTAINER name <name@gmail.com>

# Copy from previous stage
COPY --from=firstStage /projectCommons /projectCommons
COPY --from=firstStage /home/user/.ivy2/ /home/user/.ivy2/

WORKDIR /project-demo

ADD . /project-demo

# Define default command.
CMD ["sbt", "run"]
```

But why not just do normal build? (you are copying twice the current build directory inside the image for some reason, one of the `ADD` may be redundant)

```
FROM project-commons:v1

MAINTAINER name <name@gmail.com>

ADD  . /home/user/.ivy2/local/project-commons_2.12/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/project-commons_2.12.jar

WORKDIR /project-demo

ADD . /project-demo

# Define default command.
CMD ["sbt", "run"]
```

Comment: problem still persists

Comment: @swaheed you need to run the image and go inside the container and check all the required files exists

Comment: i got the exception when running the image

Comment: use `docker run --rm -it <yourimage> bash`, it will replace the sbt command